# Capture "Enter Key" to initiate command button click in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to use a userform to input username/password. It works great when the command button is click but I want to also capture when the "Enter Key" is hit to initiate the command button click event. It uses a label caption to determine which state it is in, either username or password and does a username validation to make sure it is a proper email address. I am trying to get it to work both ways, by hitting the command button to initiate or by hitting the "Enter Key". Right now I have to hit the "Enter Key' twice to get it to work.

```
Private Const EMAIL_REGEX As String = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
Private IsEnteringUsername As Boolean

Private Sub CBUserName_Click()
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = EMAIL_REGEX

    If regex.Test(UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value) Then
        M8Username = UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value
        LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Password"
        CBUserName.Visible = False
        CBPassWord.Visible = True
        UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value = ""
        UsernamePasswordTextBox.PasswordChar = "*"
        UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Username!"
        UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value = ""
        UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus
    End If

    Set regex = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CBPassWord_Click()
    M8Password = UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value
    LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Username"
    CBUserName.Visible = True
    CBPassWord.Visible = False
    UsernamePasswordTextBox.PasswordChar = ""
    Me.Hide
    GetJobs
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value = ""
    LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Username"
    UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus
    CBUserName.Visible = True
    CBPassWord.Visible = False
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)
    IsEnteringUsername = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a valid Username & Password to use this program"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim regex As Object

    If KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn Then
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regex.Global = True
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
        regex.Pattern = EMAIL_REGEX

        If IsEnteringUsername Then
            If regex.Test(UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value) Then
                M8Username = UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value
                LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Password"
                CBUserName.Visible = False
                CBPassWord.Visible = True
                UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value = ""
                UsernamePasswordTextBox.PasswordChar = "*"
                UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid Username!"
                UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value = ""
                UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus
            End If
        Else
            M8Password = UsernamePasswordTextBox.Value
            LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Username"
            CBUserName.Visible = True
            CBPassWord.Visible = False
            UsernamePasswordTextBox.PasswordChar = ""
        End If

        Set regex = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

New code:

```
Private Sub UsernamePasswordTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   
    If KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn Then
        If LbUserPass.Caption = "Please enter your Username" Then
            Call CBUserName_Click
        Else
            Call CBPassWord_Click
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try Private `Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)`   `If KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn Then` `CBUserName_Click` `End If` `End Sub`.

Comment: I tried it before but went ahead and tried it again. It doesn't seem to see the vbKeyReturn and never calls the sub. I still have to hit the "Enter Key" twice. Once to shift the selection from the textbox to the command button and a second time to initiate the command button click.

Comment: But this is an event of `UserForm`! You need to firstly click on it, to make it receive the focus and only after that the event will be triggered. Or use it on  a different (relevant) control. The one where you write user/password (with a preliminary check if the other text box is filled)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Userform_KeyDown` won't fire if a control has focus. Catch Enter in `TextBox_KeyDown` instead, the side effect is TextBox losing focus.

```vb
Private Sub UsernamePasswordTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Call CBUserName_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I modified it slightly to determine if it was the CBUsername or CBPassword that was needed and this works great. (Added the code above). A second issue arouse that I do not understand. It calls the appropriate click event but when the code runs through the click event it does not execute the UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus. The focus stays on the commandbuttons, which ever one was executed. How do I get it to shift the focus back to the textbox.

Comment: Commandbotton will get focus after `KeyDown` event no matter if there is `UsernamePasswordTextBox.SetFocus`  or not. It is the side effect which is mentioned in my reply. Hope others have a better solution to fix it.